# Is it safe to expand this Macintosh HD partition?

Tags: bootcamp, partition

A few years a go a friend of mine help me set up a partition on my MacBook air to allow me to run Windows 8.

About a year ago I decided I didn't want it anymore, and with the help of the internet, I tried but mangled the uninstallation. I thought I had uninstalled it but didn't see any improvement in space on the Mac side of things.

I thought I had issues because when I started up my laptop, I was still getting the windows start up (albeit broken beyond repair.) I now believe that this is just leftover files trying to boot what's already there.

Here is what I'm left with in Disk Utility:
[image]

Is it safe for me to try to expand the partition back to it's original size? I can move the line with no issues. Do I risk losing data?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe for me to try to expand the partition back to it's original size?

Yes, it should be safe to try to expand the partition back to its size. You can do this either by dragging the line or typing a number larger than 251 in the "Size" box.

> Do I risk losing data?

Any time you make changes to a drive (including resizing a partition), you risk losing data. I would argue that the risk is small but you should ALWAYS have an up-to-date backup. Make a backup immediately before you attempt the resize.